# Changing default \citet font in biblatex

Tags: fonts, biblatex, citing, small-caps

I'm using `biblatex` to manage my citation in a `natbib` style :

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=6,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

However when I use the `\citet` command, the author's name is in a `\textsc` font, I would like to change this behavior so that the font used is the default one, but I could not find how to do this in `biblatex`'s documentation.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess you're also using `\usepackage[french]{babel}`? The French module in `biblatex` (`french.lbx`) formats last names in small capitals by providing this "local" definition of the `\mkbibnamelast` command:

```
\protected\def\mkbibnamelast#1{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{#1}}}
```

To restore this command to its "global" definition add the following to your preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamelast}
```

In `biblatex.def` the global definition is:

```
\newcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}
```

You can redefine this via `\renewcommand*`. The code in `\DefineBibliographyExtras` is hooked into citation commands and bibliography drivers. So the French definition will simply be restored to the "current" global definition.

Comment: You are right, I am indeed using babel french. This answers perfectly my question!

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, this is no longer up to date, now it should be `\mkbibnamefamily` instead of `\mkbibnamelast`

Answer (score 8):

**Update** (with `babel-french` v. 3.2a 2016-03-18)

The command `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamelast}` no longer works.

To disable small caps in names in french language, add in the preamble the following command:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
```

Comment: See also [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864) for a survey of other changes in `biblatex` 3.3. The issue is not with `babel-french`, but rather with `biblatex` 3.3.

Comment: \What would be the converse: to restore the small caps? it seems in 2023, they are not used anymore...