# How to remove author name default capitalization?

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

According to biblatex doc (p.80-81) :

> \Parencite is similar to \parencite but capitalizes the name prefix of
>   the first name in the citation if the useprefix option is enabled,
>   provided that there is a name prefix and the citation style prints any
>   name at all.
>
> \Textcite is similar to \textcite but capitalizes the name prefix of
>   the first name in the citation if the useprefix option is enabled,
>   provided that there is a name prefix.

My problem is that `\parencite` and `\textcite` capitalize the author name by default. Therefore, there is no difference between these commands (`\textcite` has the same behavior than `\Textcite`). I am using authoryear-comp style.

It it a big problem for me because I cannot cite using `\textcite`. Indeed it will produces something like "according to NAME (2008), there is ...". The capitalized author name is ugly.

MWE : [image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{author00:_title,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2000}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
     hyperref,
     backend=biber,
     isbn=false,
     doi=false,
     url=false,
     ]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\noindent \verb+\parencite{author00:_title}+ :  \parencite{author00:_title}\\
\verb+\Parencite{author00:_title}+ : \Parencite{author00:_title}\\
\verb+\textcite{author00:_title}+ : \textcite{author00:_title}\\
\verb+\Textcite{author00:_title}+ : \Textcite{author00:_title}

%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding what “prefix” is about; it's for cases like "L. van Beethoven”; if `useprefix=true` is given in the options, `\textcite` will print “van Beethoven”, while `\Textcite` will print “Van Beethoven”.

Comment: This issue is related to your language `french`. Inside the language specific declaration you will find: `\protected\def\mkbibnamelast#1{%
    \textsc{\textnohyphenation{#1}}}%`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel ok. How can I change that?

Comment: I added a couple of fixes to your code. If you want `filecontents` to have its effect, you have to load it before the environment; it's better to use `\jobname` as a name in example code, so it won't clutter any other file; last, `\addbibresource` is to be preferred to `\bibliography` (the `.bib` extension is necessary).

Comment: Remove `french` ;-) or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/changing-default-citet-font-in-biblatex

Comment: @egreg thanks. I still use `\bibliography` instead of `\addbibresource` because I cite with reftex (C-c [) which does not understand it (error : no valid bibliography).